# Jquery toggle command triggers unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a webpage which contains one section called *'answer'*. The *'answer'* section should be hidden until users click the *'show-answer'* hyper link.

So I use JQuery toggle command to achieve this:

```
 $('.show-answer').toggle(function() { show_answer ...} , 
                                      function() {hide_answer ...} )
```

It works well by itself.

However, I got a problem when I add another form on the same page. When the form is submitted, I redirect it to this page with an anchor `"#xxx"` appended in the end.

Then I found that the toggle function got triggered unexpectedly. Basically, if the *'answer'* section is hidden before the form submitted, it becomes visible after the browser is redirected to the page.

Comment: you might want to add a is(":visible") method to check if the answer is being shown after the redirect to handle it. I'm assuming you are redirecting the the same page with the hash for the second form.

Comment: Do you have any click handler for toggling this ?

Answer (score 0):

May be using a click handler will help you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.answer').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.show-answer').toggle('show');  
        //Or  use the following      
        //$('.show-answer').slideToggle();                   
    });
});
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wxFFk/2/).

Comment: Thanks. However, seems the click function will be triggered when I redirect the browser to the page. It is the same problem as I experienced using toggle.